# Need help to parse the JSON in android

Tags: android, json

I need to get the id from this JSON.

```
{"previous_cursor_str":"0","next_cursor":0,"ids":[494942776,459450174,446965652,413869166,230653243,303016940,301473992,299765702],"previous_cursor":0,"next_cursor_str":"0"}
```

This json is the response from a url.

I tried the following, to get the id.

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("url");  
            JSONObject  id = json.getJSONObject("ids");
                Log.v("id....>>",id+"");
```

got the error.

```
02-17 22:34:10.995: W/System.err(418): org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["id"] not found.
```

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON is using "ids" not "id".

Comment: sorry.. I posted wrongly. its ids in my code. And got that error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
JSONObject  id = json.getJSONObject("id");
```

with

```
JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("ids");
```

Then loop through that...

Comment: note that it's "ids" not "id". It's impossible to get the same error if you use "ids".

Comment: I parse the following url "http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=worldwinnermani&cursor=-1"  when I print the response, I got this exception. 02-18 07:31:05.384: V/Json response(13803): {"error":"इस विधि को जीईटी की आवश्यकता है.","request":"\/1\/followers\/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi"}

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "ids" JSONArrayObject.

```
JSONArray  ids = json.getJSONArray("ids");
id = ids.getString(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create Json object, if you are getting response as string use this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString);
```

Then get `ids` JSONArray from it as :

```
JSONArray idArr = obj.getJSONArray("ids");
```

Now you have list of ids, to get first id use :

```
idArr.getLong(0)
```